# Is it a good/clever idea to trick a hacker into thinking an encryption is md5, when it is not?

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography

```
$clear_text = "hello";
$salt_ = sha1("758hF4H7gJi98U6o");
$salt = substr($salt_, 0, 12);
$hash = substr(hash("sha512", $clear_text), 0, 20).$salt;
```

As you can see, `$hash` generates a 32 character string, making it look identical to md5. So a hacker will be trying to decrpyt this *md5 hash* when in fact it is nothing like that!
Would this be cunning, and would it be a good idea?

Comment: I'd use 128 bit password hashes, but not to trick attackers. Using larger hashes is simply useless. | Also if you're talking about password hashes, then plain SHA-512 like in your example is no good choice. Use bcrypt, scrpyt or PBKDF2.

Comment: (It's also not a good idea to trick yourself into thinking that md5 is an encryption)

Comment: thanks! so you are saying you would not try and trick the attacker?

Comment: I'm still trying to find the words to explain why no, but mostly I'm just stuck with http://i.imgur.com/bazqF.gif as a reaction. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25585/is-my-developers-home-brew-password-security-right-or-wrong-and-why.

Comment: Concatenating a secret key storied in a config file or the source code to the salt is better than trying to hide how you hash. Your scheme is broken if an attacker sees your source, and the key scheme can't be broken unless the attacker sees the source. So using a key is at least as good as your scheme (and much better in practice)

Comment: I'm tagging this PHP, because I guess this is a PHP code sample (and most languages don't output hexadecimals as output of a hash function, they simply - and correctly - output the bytes themselves)

Comment: MD5 is not encryption!

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to invent your own crypto, use standardized hashing algorithms like  bcrypt, scrypt or PBKDF2.

Please refer to:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

There is a principle in security which is called [Kirckhoff's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle), one of the rules is "It must not be required to be secret, and it must be able to fall into the hands of the enemy without inconvenience" Suggest the attacker has access to your machine and is able to dump your source files as well as your database it won't take him very long to discover your algorithm.

Now from there your own rolled algorithm doesn't really provide any additional protection from normal sha512+salt. The speed at which he would be able to attack the hashes would be the same with or without your algorithm. Meaning your scheme is useless once the algorithm as been found.

Answer (score 1):

```
$salt_ = sha1("758hF4H7gJi98U6o");
```

Hashing entropy does not provide better entropy. See [What should be used as a salt?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8015/what-should-be-used-as-a-salt). Summary: encode a unique and unpredictable value.

```
$hash = substr(hash("sha512", $clear_text), 0, 20).$salt;
```

You should use multiple iterations of hashing. See [How to securely hash passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords). Summary: PBKDF2, BCrypt, SCrypt provide this.

> Would this be cunning

No, and it'd be essentially irrelevant if your code was read as well.

> and would it be a good idea

It'd more likely be a nuisance for anybody who ever had to maintain it in the future. It's probably not a *bad* idea on the face of it in that altering the hash format may confuse somebody, but you can consider that in-hand with reading [The valid role of obscurity](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2430/the-valid-role-of-obscurity). If you're going to alter the hash format, spend that effort to encrypt it so it can't be attacked without the encryption key. The effort to find the key would probably be the same, but it'd be a much easier decision to defend.